# Search returns line number

Tags: asp-classic

Im trying to search for something in a textfile and have the line number returned.
I have tried getting the line number by using instr but that timed out the script.

```
<%
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("evewhdb.txt"), 1)

FSOContents = objTextFile.readline
SResult = InStr(1,FSOContents,"A123456",1)

If Sresult <>0 Then
    Response.Write "line is: " & objTextFile.Line

Else
    Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    Loop
End If

Set objFSO = nothing
Set objTextFile = nothing
%>
```

Anyway, this doesn't work, so the question is:
Is there any way to have the line number returned on searching a textfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the loop contain the `readline`, so that it fetches the next row, otherwise it goes into an infinite loop, and that is why it times out, not because you are using `InStr`

You also only fire the `InStr` once, before the loop, so it would only ever find  it if it was in the first line.  Again that needs to be inside the loop.

Also I've changed it so that it will find multiple occurrences, if you don't want that then you have to add another condition to the `Do While`  I've also added a -1 to the response, otherwise it is offset by one.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("evewhdb.txt"), 1)

FSOContents = objTextFile.readline
Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    SResult = InStr(1,FSOContents,"A123456",1)
    If Sresult <>0 Then
        Response.Write "line is: " & objTextFile.Line  - 1 & "<BR>"
    End If
    FSOContents = objTextFile.readline
Loop

Set objFSO = nothing
Set objTextFile = nothing
```